# SSD HD works for 10 seconds and shuts down

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I used Samsung MZ7LN256HCHP SSD Hard-Drive for quite a while. Yesterday it broke.
It didn't turned on the operation system (windows 10) and just stuck on loading.
On rare cases it did turned it on, but stuck on login screen.

I had an external HDD (not SSD), so I opened the case, and removed that device plugged to the HDD to use it with a USB cable as external device.

I tried 2 computers, plugged the SSD using the USB cable, and it worked for 10 seconds, after it just freezes without an option to do anything.
I tried running block error tests, I tried copying the data from the SSD, but nothing works. after 10 seconds, it just shuts down (the LED still on but stops flashing).

Is there a way recovering the SSD? maybe saving the data (it is clearly there)? maybe that device I took from the HDD, is not compatible with SSD?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could give this a Try [SSD Recovery Software](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/other-recovery-software/SSD-drive-recovery.htm) and see if it does the same when it trys to accsess the disc. Does it show up in the bios when turning on your computer? After that you could see if [Gparted Live Disc](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) could see how the health is and possibly bring it back to life. If not its possible some is shorted out inside.

Comment: With SSD Recovery Software I couldn't complete the process because after 10 sec it shuts down. With Gparted, I couldn't figure what I should do there, but its health is irrelevant because I am pretty sure it's broke. I want to restore the data.